# Swift Embed Navigation Controller

Tags: swift, uinavigationbar

I have a table view controller as my second view controller, and it seems that the only to include a back button on the navigation bar is to embed a navigation controller back to the first view controller. When I embed the navigation controller to the first view controller, this puts a back button on the table VC. My issue is when I hit back, it moves back to the first VC, but the back button still remains. When I hit this back button, it will move back to the second view controller. This seems like a function of the embed feature, but I was wondering if there was a way to remove that, or another way I can input a navigation bar (with back button) on the second VC.

Comment: It'll be better if you insert some code or screenshot about the storyboard

Comment: "the only [way] to include a back button on the navigation bar is to embed a navigation controller back to the first view"  No.  It depends on how you present the next navigation.  Take a close look at the way view controller shifts: horizontally or verticall.